# Why is 3-Coloring in PQMA(2)?

Tags: measurement, complexity-theory, qma

I'm reading https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.0738 about the complexity of PQMA(2) and its relation to NP. It describes a PQMA(2) protocol (3.1) for 3-coloring which contains the following check:

> For both $|\psi⟩$ and $|\phi⟩$, measure the index part of the register and the
> color part separately in the Fourier basis. **If the outcome of the**
> **measurement of the color part is $F_3|0⟩$** and the outcome of the index
> part is not $F_n|0⟩$, then reject.

I highlighted the part I am having trouble with in bold. The core of my problem might be some basic misunderstanding with how to measure in different bases so I'll give a brief description of my thought process. If I understood it correctly, measuring in the Fourier basis means applying a Fourier transform $F$ to a state $|x⟩$ and then performing a measurement on the resulting $F|x⟩$. However, this way I don't understand how it is possible to perform the check of whether the color part is $F_3|0⟩$. For example, both $F|0⟩$ and $F|1⟩$ have a certain probability of being measured as - say - $|0⟩$ so the measurement doesn't really tell me anything about the initial state. How do I know whether the color register was in exactly $F_3|0⟩$ as opposed to any other superposition prior to my measurement?

The proof of Lemma 3.2 only seems to say that when I measure the color register and get $|0⟩$, I know that the index register is in state $F_n|0⟩$, but that doesn't tell me whether the color register was in $F_3|0⟩$ prior to the measurement, does it?

It's probably important that the protocol requires us to measure the index part in the fourier basis, too. If I get $|0⟩$ for the color register, I know that the index is in $F_n|0⟩$ and measuring that in the fourier basis would give me $|0⟩$. Therefore, I know that the overall state has to be $|00⟩$ once I measure the color register and get $|0⟩$ but I'm still not sure why thats useful in this context.